# LaunchDarkly dotnet-server-sdk Never Inializes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, launchdarkly

LaunchDarkly fails to ever initialize.  If I use a bad sdk key, it fails as expected, and immediately.  If I use the correct key, it times out after the default timeout period, and never initalizes.  Has anyone experienced this?

I am using the latest stable dotnet sdk v8 installed via NuGet on a .NET Framework 4.8 MVC application.  I will mention that it worked briefly, so I think it might be an LD specific issue vs a coding issue.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After much gnashing of teeth, it turned out to be a bug in the latest version and specific to .NET Framework 4.8.  I downgraded my NuGet package to 7.1.0 and it worked again.

I submitted this issue to LaunchDarkly.

https://github.com/launchdarkly/dotnet-server-sdk/issues/184

Hope this helps!